# Do we have a method like MGLSourceChanged: in map box sdk iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapbox

Hi I was working with MapBox SDK and had to face a situation where I want to get a callback method or a normal method which is called when the source of the Mapbox is changed. Does this map box have some listener or notifier to let the user know the source(geoJSON) has changed. If there is some method like didUpdateMGLSource: do let me know. I am stuck in this scenario. I need all you expert advices. Thanks in advance. Happy Coding. :)